# Find $dy/dx$ if $xe^{9y}+y^4\sin(4x)=e^{8x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

If $xe^{9y}+y^4\sin(4x)=e^{8x}$ implicitly defines $y$ as a function of $x$ then what is $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$?

So far, I have made the following steps:

1) Get all parts of the equation onto one side

2) Find the derivative of the whole equation

3) This equals $9e^{9y}+y^4(4cos(4x))+4y^3(sin(4x))-8e^{8x}$

4) Now, I think I am to get 'y' by itself. However, I am not sure how to do this, since there are $y$ variables as exponents, as well as non-exponent $y$ variables.

Does anyone know how I may find the derivative of this function?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitl differentiation means that we need to treat $y$ as a function of $x$ and apply Chain Rule. You also forgot to apply Product Rule to the first term. The derivative of the first term is:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}[xe^{9y}]
&= x\left[\frac{d}{dx}e^{9y}\right] + \left[\frac{d}{dx}x\right]e^{9y} \\
&= xe^{9y}\left[\frac{d}{dx}9y\right] + \left[1\right]e^{9y} \\
&= xe^{9y} \left[9\frac{dy}{dx}\right] + e^{9y} \\
&= 9xe^{9y}y' + e^{9y} \\
\end{align*}
Now do the same thing for the second term, then solve for $y'$.

Comment: I have got 9e^(9y)xy'+e^(9y)+y^4(4cos(4x))+4y^3(sin(4x))-8e^(8x). So, to get y' by itself, I moved everything onto one side except y'. This is (-e^(9y)-y^4(4cos(4x))-4y^3(sin(4x))+8e^(8x))/(9e^(9y)x)=y'. Does this answer seem correct to you?